# jQuery detect if document contains an id matching the href of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, href, matching

I've written a function that adds hrefs to an alphabetical navigation bar. I made it so each letter section gives itself an ID. I want to make it so in the event there isn't for example a "C" section, I could add a class to the link linking to #c that would disable it. Here's what I have so far:

```
 <ul class="no-bullet inline">
      <li><a class="scroller"><strong>A</strong></a></li>
      <li><a class="scroller"><strong>B</strong></a></li>
      <li><a class="scroller"><strong>C</strong></a></li>
</ul>

  <div class="space-above space-below letter-section">
       <h4 class="alpha-heading"><strong>A</strong></h4>
        <ul class="no-bullet">
             <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
             <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
             <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
         </ul>
   </div>
 <div class="space-above space-below letter-section">
       <h4 class="alpha-heading"><strong>A</strong></h4>
        <ul class="no-bullet">
             <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
             <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
             <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
         </ul>
   </div>
 <script>
 function alphaLink() {
       var alphaLink = $(this);
       var alphaLinkRef = "#" + alphaLink.text().toLowerCase();
       $(alphaLink).attr("href", alphaLinkRef);
   };
   $('.scroller').each(alphaLink);

   //assigns each content section an ID

   function alphaID() {
       var section = $(this);
       var sectionID = section.text().toLowerCase();
       $(section).attr("ID", sectionID);
   };
   $('.alpha-heading').each(alphaID);

linkMatch function(){
   var link = $(this);
    if(link.length <= 0) {
    $(this).addclass("disabled");
}

$("scroller").each(linkMatch);
</script>
```

Comment: And what is your question ? Does it not work ?

Comment: I can't get the function to search through the IDs to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Jeremiah's code and altered it slightly to do what I needed it to do. Thanks so much for all the answers- here was the final product:

```
   function findID(ID) {
     var exists = false;
     if ($(ID).length > 0) {
      exists = true;
     }
     return exists;
 }

 function matchLink() {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     if (!findID(href)) {
         // Doesn't exist
         $(this).addClass('alpha-disabled');
     }
 };
 $('.scroller').each(matchLink);
```

Comment: You should mark my answer as accepted to help my reputation! Glad it helped though. One thing to note that you may have already considered is that, if you pass findID a string without a leading # it won't work. You could add some logic to check for # and if it doesn't exist, add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Here is an example:

```
function linkMatch(index, elem){
    var link = elem,
        heading = $(".alpha-heading");

    var linkHref = link.attr("href").substring(1, link.attr("href").length);

    if(typeof(heading[index]) != "undefined") {
        if(linkHref != heading[index].getAttribute("id")) {
            link.addClass("disabled");
        }
    }
}

$(".scroller").each(function(index) {
    linkMatch(index, $(this));
});
```

**Edit**
I've just edited my code, because I forgot to write `length` inside `linkHref` variable

Comment: there's a couple of errors in this code- once I fixed the syntax errors this almost worked. However, it's adding the disabled class to all the links not just the one without anything to link to.

Comment: Do you mean this?

Comment: function linkMatch(index, elem){
        var link = elem;
        var heading = $(".alpha-heading");
        var linkHref = link.attr("href").substring(1, link.attr("href"));

        if(typeof(heading[index]) != "undefined") {
            if(linkHref != heading[index].getAttribute("id")) {
                link.addClass("disabled");
            }
        }
    }

    $(".scroller").each(function(index) {
        linkMatch(index, $(this));
    });

Because this almost works- however, it adds disabled to everything.

Comment: you were missing ")" after ("href"). This almost works now, It adds disabled to everything tho. I need it to add disabled to links that have nothing to link to on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If the HREF is something like '#C', take a look at this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function(i,e){
     var href = $(this).attr('href')
     if(!findID(href)){
        // Doesn't exist
        $(this).addClass('disabled');
     }
  })
    function findID(ID){
    var exists = false;
    if($(ID).length > 0){
        exists = true;
    }
    return exists;
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATED!** Sorry I overlooked that you wanted to disable the link, not on click. [Here is a JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhuteLat/1/) if you inspect the link with href="$find-someting-else" you'll see it has the class disabled whereas the other one does not.

Comment: I need this to disable the link on page load not on click.

Comment: Updated, that should do it